# Значение option в datalist при клике

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список вариантов datalist. Как при клику на один из option вивести его значение

```
 <input list="manufacturer" >
          <datalist id="manufacturer">
            <option >1</option>
            <option>22</option>
          </datalist>
          </input><br>
```

Нашел скрипт который выводит для select но для datalist нет

```
 function getManufacturer() {
                var e = document.getElementById('manufacturer');
                console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex]);
                document.getElementById('manufacturer');
                console.log(document.getElementById('manufacturer'));
          }
```

Comment: вывести куда? он автоматически же подставляет значение в input при клике. А из него уже получить значение очень легко

Comment: Ну получить точнее!

Comment: `onchange` на `input` и там уже можно получить через `e.target.value`

Comment: Мне нужно получить значение при клике на <option>.Я знаю что onchange работатет, но не так как мне нужно

Comment: Так как Вам нужно? Обновите вопрос, что бы нам было понятно, чего Вы хотите добиться.